# Difference between various ways of using memset function

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, sizeof, memset

What is the difference between the following three commands?

Suppose we declare an array arr having 10 elements.

```
int arr[10];
```

Now the commands are:

Command 1:

```
memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
```

and
Command 2:

```
memset(arr,0,10*sizeof(int));
```

These two commands are running smoothly in an program but the following command is not

Command 3:

```
memset(arr,0,10);
```

So what is the difference between the 3 commands?

Comment: Are you sure you're in C++ and not in C?

Comment: Because the size of an int is normally not 1 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr))` fills `arr` with `sizeof(arr)` zeros -- as bytes. `sizeof(arr)` is correct in this case, but beware using this approach on pointers rather than arrays.

`memset(arr,0,10*sizeof(int))` fills `arr` with `10*sizeof(int)` zeros, again as bytes. This is once again the correct size *in this case*. This is more fragile than the first. What if `arr` does not contain 10 elements, and what if the type of each element is not `int`. For example, you find you are getting overflow and change `int arr[10]` to `long long arr[10]`.

`memset(arr,0,10)` fills the first 10 bytes of `arr` with zeros. This clearly is not what you want.

None of these is very C++-like. It would be much better to use `std::fill`, which you get from the `<algorithm>` header file. For example, `std::fill (a, a+10, 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Case #1: `sizeof(arr)` returns 10 * sizeof(int)

Case #2: `sizeof(int) * 10` returns the same thing

Case #3: `10` returns 10

An int takes up more than one byte (usually 4 on 32 bit). So if you did `40` for case three, it would probably work. But never actually do that.

Answer (score 2):

`memset`'s 3rd paranneter is how many *bytes* to fill.  So here you're telling `memset` to set 10 bytes:

```
memset(arr,0,10);
```

But `arr` isn't necesarrily 10 bytes.  (In fact, it's not)  You need to know how many *bytes* are in `arr`, not how many elements.

The size of an `int` is not guaranteed to be 1 byte.  On most modern PC-type hardware, it's going to be 4 bytes.

You should not assume the size of any particular datatype, except `char` which is guaranteed to be 1 byte exactly.  For everything else, you must determine the size of it (at compile time) by using `sizeof`.